# Replace characters with a dictionary only outside of double quotes

Tags: java, regex

My code:

```java
String text="üçgen: \"üçgenin üç köşesi vardır\"";
//Translate: triangle: "a triangle has three corners"

String[] trChars = {"ç", "ğ", "ö", "ş", "ı", "ü", "Ç", "Ğ", "Ö", "Ş", "İ", "Ü"};
String[] enChars = {"c", "g", "o", "s", "i", "u", "C", "G", "O", "S", "I", "U"};
for (int i = 0; i < trChars.length; i++) {
    String regex = "(?<!\")"+ trChars[i] + "(?![\\w\\s]*[\"])";
    text = text.replaceAll(regex, enChars[i]);
}
System.out.println(text);
```

Result:

```
ucgen: "ücgenin uc kosesi vardır"
```

My desired result:

```
ucgen: "üçgenin üç köşesi vardır"
```

Some of the characters in quotes have changed and some have not, while they all should stay the same.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Are you required to use a regular expression?  This task would be easier without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the code by creating a single dictionary with keys to search for and values to replace with, and only replace the matches once they are found not inside double quotes:

```java
String text="üçgen: \"üçgenin üç köşesi vardır\"";
//Translate: triangle: "a triangle has three corners"
 
String[] trChars = {"ç", "ğ", "ö", "ş", "ı", "ü", "Ç", "Ğ", "Ö", "Ş", "İ", "Ü"};
String[] enChars = {"c", "g", "o", "s", "i", "u", "C", "G", "O", "S", "I", "U"};
 
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < trChars.length; i++) {
    dictionary.put(trChars[i], enChars[i]);
}
 
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|([" + String.join("", trChars) + "])").matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, dictionary.get(m.group(1)));
    } else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, m.group());
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
// => ucgen: "üçgenin üç köşesi vardır"
```

See the [Java code online](https://ideone.com/yhITSI).

The regex will look like  `"[^"]*"|([çğöşıüÇĞÖŞİÜ])` and once the match is found and Group 1 is not empty, `dictionary.get(m.group(1))` will fetch the corresponding ASCII value for the found Turkish letter. Else, the string between double quotes will be returned as is.

Comment: This is wrong. The contents of the quotation mark should not change. My want result: ucgen: "üçgenin üç köşesi vardır"

Comment: @HAK Aha, so that is the question. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

String indexing is fast and efficient. I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
public class Turk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String text = "üçgen: \"üçgenin üç köşesi vardır\"";
            // Translate: triangle: "a triangle has three corners"

            System.out.println(text);
            String trChars = "çğöşıüÇĞÖŞİÜ";
            String enChars = "cgosiuCGOSIU";
            StringBuilder transliteration = new StringBuilder(text.length());
            boolean transliterate = true;
            int ix = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
                char c = text.charAt(i);
                if (c == '"') {
                    transliterate = !transliterate;
                }
                if ((ix = trChars.indexOf(c)) >= 0 && transliterate) {
                    transliteration.append(enChars.charAt(ix));
                } else {
                    transliteration.append(c);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(transliteration.toString());

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. The contents of the quotation mark should not change. My want result: ucgen: "üçgenin üç köşesi vardır". Your Result: ucgen: "ucgenin uc kosesi vardir".

Comment: OK. I slightly misunderstood the requirement

Comment: That should be OK now

Comment: The try/catch is not needed.  (And catching Throwable is highly undesirable practice, because things like NullPointerException and IndexOutOfBoundsException are programmer errors that should be exposed and fixed, not suppressed.)

Comment: You need to read (my template 'scratch pad') code again. Nothing is suppressed

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "üçgen: \"üçgenin üç köşesi vardır\"";

    String[] trChars = {"ç", "ğ", "ö", "ş", "ı", "ü", "Ç", "Ğ", "Ö", "Ş", "İ", "Ü"};
    String[] enChars = {"c", "g", "o", "s", "i", "u", "C", "G", "O", "S", "I", "U"};

    Map<String, String> map = IntStream.range(0, trChars.length)
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> trChars[i], i -> enChars[i]));
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|(.)");

    String trancelated = pat.matcher(text)
        .replaceAll(m -> m.group(1) != null
            ? map.getOrDefault(m.group(), m.group()) : m.group());
    System.out.println(trancelated);
}
```

output:

```
ucgen: "üçgenin üç köşesi vardır"
```

Comment: I do not think it is an unclear question, and cast a reopen vote. If you feel the same please cast your reopen vote, too.